# PHP Class not found even though module is installed

Tags: php, mongodb, include, pear

I am trying to use the mongodb PHP module. I have installed it using pecl and written it into my php.ini. Calling and echoeing `get_loaded_extensions()` correctly displays the extension `mongodb`. However, my code which follows the [official guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/) throws the error `class MongoDB\Client not found`. How do I fix this? Do I need to include the module first somehow?

My code:

```php
<?php
var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());
$client = new MongoDB\Client(
    'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-address>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
);
```

I am hosting an nginx server on my raspberry pi with rasbian lite installed, if that matters.

Comment: Most likely you only loaded this in your `CLI SAPI`'s loaded configuration file and not your web SAPI. If you did load them in both you gotta remember to restart your web SAPI's php workers to load the extension. Check `phpinfo()` in the **correct SAPI** to be sure.

Comment: @Sherif honestly I don't really understand SAPIS, but on a different machine in the same network, I can access the site. `phpinfo()` shows the right ini file and has a section for the mongodb module.

Comment: You did this from the command line right? So, create a file with `<?php phpinfo();` in it. Open it from your web browser, and look for **Loaded configuration (php.in) file**. That's the file you want to stick `extension=mongodb.so` in. Then restart fpm or apache httpd.

Comment: @Sherif in the command line, I said `sudo systemctl start nginx` to start my nginx server. Now from a different machine, I can access the php file on the server and see in the phpinfo that everything is loaded correctly. Excuse me if this is a dumb question, but where except the command line should I do this?

Comment: If everything is showing up fine in phpinfo() then where do you get the error that the class doesn't exist? Do you run that script from the web or on the command line?

Comment: Just to be clear, `MongoDB\Client` is not a class in `mongodb.so`. It's in the old legacy extension called `mongo.so`, which is not recommended. You are aware of this fact, right?

Comment: Wait what? I wasn't - [The guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/) shows it as the example

Answer (score 1):

`MongoDB\Client` is a php library that deals with php mongodb driver which is `mongodb` extension that you see using `get_loaded_extensions()`. To use the `MongoDB\Client` class you need to download the library named [mongodb/mongodb](https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/mongodb).

To do this first in your project root create a folder with whatever name you prefer, for example, `mongodb_test` in our case; Now create a file named **composer.json** file and put the following code in it:

```
{
    "require": {
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.2"
    }
}
```

Then run the following command on your command line tool:

```
php composer.phar install
```

or the following command if composer is installed globally

```
composer install
```

Next up, in the same directory/folder create a new file with any name and put the following code to test it in the localhost for example.

```
<?php

// Notice here. This is a must that you're missing
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Create client object
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

// Gets collection
$collection = $client->demo->beers;

// Inserts data
$result = $collection->insertOne(['name' => 'Hinterland', 'brewery' => 'BrewDog']);

echo 'Inserted with Object ID: ' . $result->getInsertedId() . '<br>';

// Fetches data
$result = $collection->find(['name' => 'Hinterland']);

// Iterates over data
foreach ($result as $entry) {
    echo $entry['_id'], ': ', $entry['name'], "\n";
}
```

Hope this would help you understand.